# How to pass formbean/object from jsp to action class in struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a jsp page with some input fields in it.
on submit want to pass all the values in as bean attribute so that no need to set all the individual fields to be set in hidden field.

Comment: And the problem is ?

Comment: Setting some hidden fields in S2 is extremely useful especially if you want to submit some input fields, because S2 has a special meaning them. But,  please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

In my Jsp page i was displaying 3 list of bean using forEach jstl and all list values are displaying in input fields.
User can modify the input field values.
On submit of the page in action I require the modified values of input fields inside c:forEach.

I found the solution.
Like we will be using request.getParameter("") for any individual input field i used **request.getParameterValues("fieldName");** which will return a string array of values of input fields inside my c:forEach

Comment: With S2 you don't need to use `request.getParameter...`.

Comment: yes but i have simple input fields not s:textfields